# How to check if a user is authenticated on 2 different web apps?

Tags: php, python, mysql, cookies, web-applications

I've been looking around the Internet but I cannot find anything related to my specific case online.

Let's assume there are 2 web applications. `wa1` and `wa2`. `wa1` is written in PHP, located on `domain1.com` and `wa2` is written in Python, located on `domain2.com`. There is a common database `user_info` which stores user information such as usernames and passwords, and another database `user_logged_in` which lists users and their sessions.

The user will authenticate through `wa1`. How can I check if the user is authenticated in `wa2`, if I cannot use remote MySQL to access the `user_logged_in` database? Is it possible to set a cookie such that the site on `domain2.com` can read the cookie set by `domain1.com`?

Comment: You can't read cookies belonging to a different website than yours. See https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/49636/can-a-webpage-read-another-pages-cookies

Comment: use Oauth2 for authentication

Comment: @DevJalla I've initially wanted to use OAuth2, however the reason being is that I am implementing the 2 webapps as part of the same "suite", and OAuth is usually used for external applications wishing to integrate into the service.

Comment: So as you say you don't have access to user_logged_in database then in  in  a simple manner no. Or else you can write  a common api which has access to logged in data so that api can verify you

Comment: you better get your remote connection to work and add a specific property to session for matching

Comment: @MASIDDIQUI how would I go about passing information to the API safely? Assuming the user is logged in, I still need to save information about his user state locally on his computer such that the website will be able to use the API to verify against the database

Comment: @xiurobert Using Oauth2 will make your life simple, Just pass the token and validate it let them be in a same"suite"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got it right, I believe that you need a Single Sign On solution.

I'd recommend that you take a look at OpenID Connect specifications.

In this scenario you will need to add a third "app", which is going to be the responsible for issuing tokens to authenticated users (some sort of Identity Server). All the user related information will be stored and managed by this service.

The apps themselves will rely on the Tokens in order to check if there's a valid user and they can fetch user information from the Identity Server.

A great option for that is IdentityServer, which is open-source: https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/

Their documentation is very good and will give you a more in-depth explanation.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes, absolutey! Single sign on is what I need